# Active to Passive voice: "Go to School Now"

Tags: sentence, passive-voice, imperatives, active-voice

How would you convert the imperative sentence: "Go to school now."
to the passive voice?

While discussing it in class, our teacher gave the following solution:
"You are ordered to go to school now."

However, I felt that this must be wrong, since the sentence is still in the active voice. It seems to be in the passive voice with reference to the verb 'order', but we need to convert the sentence with respect to the verb 'go'.

I thought of a solution:
"Let you be gone to school now."
or
"Be gone to school now."

Are any of them correct? And if not, how would you convert the sentence into passive voice?

---

### Edit:

Just realised that 'go' is an intratransitive verb. Does that mean that there won't be a passive version of it? As mentioned [here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110630042729AAijxQT):

> You CAN'T. You can only turn into passive verbs those verbs who can have the "direct object".
>   For example:
>   I eat (what do you eat?) an apple
>   I see (what do you see?) a bird
>   I read (what do you read?) a poem
>
> But if you say : I go, you can't ask "what do you go", because it doesn't make any sense! And that's why you can't write that in passive voice.

---

### Edit II:

How about "Let the school be gone to by you."?

Comment: Regarding **Edit I**, you *can* way "where do you go?". Does that make it an indirect object? *I go (where do you go?) to school* is similar to *I read (where do you read?) in school*. I was never good at the finer points of grammar, but I think your question should cover this for clarity (well, at least my clarity).

Comment: "Your presence is immediately required at a nearby educational facility, wherein, if you recall the events of the previous months, you have been enrolled as a pupil."

Comment: @PatrickM Apparently not; the verb in question must be answerable to a 'what...?' question.

Comment: @Kaz While that is correct in the meaning, I doubt my teacher would be very pleased by me adding at least half a dozen extra verbs and nouns! Haha :P

Answer (score 5):

A suitable reference is [English Practice](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/changing-imperative-sentence-passive/).

Where the verb is intransitive, as you note, the passive form is different. To create the passive, you need an object to turn into the subject of *be*.

> Active: Bring it home.
>   Passive: Let **it be brought** home.
>
> Active: Please help me.
>   Passive: Let **me be helped.**
>   Passive: **You are requested** to help me.
>
> Active: Get out. (No object)
>   Passive: **You are ordered** to get out.

A fundamental property of a passive construction is that the agent (that is, the person who is actually doing the bringing, requesting, or ordering) is not stated. All we know is that an action is done — bringing something home, helping me, or an order to get out.

In an imperative sentence like "Go to school now," there is an implied subject and object which can be made explicit in an obviously active-voice sentence: "**I order you** to go to school now." When that is made into a passive construction, the *I* is lost and the sentence becomes "You **are ordered to** go to school now."

Comment: True, but this would logically mean that tha answer to OPs question would be *Begone to school*, which in uncommon to say the least.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm not convinced that's actually passive. It's an active imperative in much the same vein as "Be rude" or "Turn green!" OED has "Really two words *be gone* (compare *be off*), long used without analysis in the imperative as expressing a single notion, and so written as one word."

Comment: I still don't get why adding 'You are ordered to' converts the sentence to the passive voice. The subject is still doing the action i.e. going to school - thus making it active. Although the subject is being acted upon by the verb 'order', as I mentioned above, that is not the verb of our interest, is it?

Comment: The crux of the 'voice' of a sentence is that in the active voice, the subject performs some action, while in the passive voice, an action is being performed on the subject.

Comment: In a passive construction, it's not possible to determine who is doing the action. The agent is not stated. "You are ordered to get out" fits that definition: it's not stated who is doing the ordering. I'll add this into the answer: it's relevant.

Comment: What about "A burger was eaten by the man."? The action-doer *is* stated.

Comment: Yes, but that's **additional** information. "The burger was eaten" is a standard passive construction. The passive voice is generally used because the agent is not necessary. However, it can be added by those who need it. [See what I did there?]

Comment: Hahahaha! Yes I did :P So the passive construction of 'Go to school now' would be 'You are ordered to go to school now'. Okay. What about the sentences I've mentioned in the question?

Comment: Which sentences? "An apple is eaten; a bird is seen; a poem is read." "The school is approached," perhaps; but none of these are intransitive verbs in imperative mood.

Comment: -1 Regarding this actual answer, it's quite wrong. The passive voice is a simple transformation of an active, transitive verb with a subject and an object into one with a subject and an optional adjust phrase, where the new subject is semantically the same as the old object and the new adjust phrase is semantically the same as the old subject. Nothing more. Intransitive verbs cannot be passivized, period. You can construct related sentences that might employ the passive voice, but those are in no way passive transformations of the origination.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: No, I was referring to 'Let the school be gone to by you' and 'Let you be gone to school'.

Comment: @siride 's comment makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew Leach's explanation is sound as far as how you might go about doing this, but the answers all sound awkward and goofy.  I think this points to a bigger point that *you shouldn't do this*.

Consider the [reasons for using passive voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Reasons_for_using_the_passive_voice).  The whole idea of passive voice is inverting the emphasis between subject and object, so it just doesn't make a whole lot of sense to do in imperative sentences.

Comment: We shouldn't - that's quite correct, but it's not really gonna help me writing "You shouldn't do this conversion" in my examination paper! Hahaha :D

Comment: Just so. This is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Well, yes, hence why I referenced your answer in case someone really, really wanted to do so. :)

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, a passive version of your imperative would be:

> School be gone to (by you)!

However:

- pragmatically, this is not absolutely equivalent, because you are in effect 'commanding' the school rather than the person (but this is always the case with active/passive pairs: they will involve shifts in focus/emphasis/scope and are never absolutely equivalent)
- we are in effect personnifying the school (that's sort of OK, you will find other examples such as "Rain be gone!", but it is definitely stylistically 'marked' and not an everyday expression)
- generally, it is pragmatically odd to make locations the subject of passives (so by the same observation, people wouldn't usually say "Birmingham was gone to by the train", "The station was left by the train" etc).

In general it's a slightly silly exercise to try and 'turn' an active imperative into a passive or vice versa, because the choice depends more on which argument of the verb is most naturally the element to be 'commanded'.

More natural examples of passive imperatives would be e.g.:

> *Be warned* that I am in a bad mood!
>
> Don't *be put off* by his appearance.

Comment: More than slightly silly, I'd say. Or, ... "More than slightly silly" would be said by me.

Comment: You can't passivize intransitive verbs, period.

Comment: @siride That's not necessarily true.

Comment: @NeilCoffey: it's quite true. The passive voice requires that there be a semantic and syntactic direct object to be promoted to subject, and intransitive verbs by definition lack this direct object. You can construct sentences that flip around arguments in various ways, but not all of them are passivization.

Comment: @siride No it doesn't!

Comment: @NeilCoffey: dude, we're talking about the definitions of things. Both passive voice and intransitive verbs are real terms with real meanings, and the two are definitionally incompatible. That you can come up with semantically-similar constructions is irrelevant. You can't make up terms, change the meaning of things or flub definitions. Deal with it.

Comment: @siride Not necessarily! We are talking about definitions of things, but the definitions are really more complex than you seem to be assuming. Go away and have a look in more detail at different subcategories of 'intransitive' and issues of the passive such as how you deal with a case such as German "Hier wurde getanzt". There is *something* in what you are saying: that in reality, apparent 'active' vs 'passive' variants of an utterance probably involve shifts in the nature of the arguments beyond simply 'turning the object into the subject'...

Comment: ...but I really don't think you can simplify things to "intransitive verbs are completely incompatible with the passive voice".

Answer (score 1):

> How would you convert the imperative sentence: "Go to school now." to
>   the passive voice?

**(1) I wouldn't.** (Check the question asked)

(2) If the question had read

> How could you convert the imperative sentence: "Go to school now."
>   into a paraphrase containing the passive voice?

I'd answer **'You can't'.**

(3) If the question had read

> Consider the imperative sentence: "Go to school now." Is there a way of saying this so that the overall sense is not totally lost, but containing the passive voice?

I'd probably answer

"You are being told to go to school now." (But I know which version would be used by sensible people.)

I'd say that this question is asking for something beyond the well-known transformation involved in 'convert[ing a] sentence ... to the passive voice'. And is thus a poorly phrased question.

Answer (score -1):

Let the school be gone to by you or you can say let the school be gone 
by you but the first one the most correctly

Comment: Did you realize that nobody is able to read your answer. All I is see a series of words. I think there's even an error in your first sentence, but as I'm not able to parse your answer I might be wrong on that. Do you mind improving your answer to make it readable, especially for non-native, i.e. language learners.