# Let it be done - grammatical analysis

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, subjunctive-mood, passive-voice

How should the phrase "Let it be done" be interpreted grammatically?

What confounds me are the following assumptions, some or all of which may be wrong:

1. "Let" implies imperative
2. "it be done" implies a subjunctive
3. the lack of an agent implies passive
4. [section 5](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subjunctive.html) of this reference says that the "let" indicates the desire for a hypothetical situation and is hence part of the subjunctive - I'm thinking that this "let" could be either a desire and a command but at this point I'm probably wrong

Given the above is "Let it be done" a correct passive transformation of "Do it"? Is this a passive-voice imperative-mood construction (in which case what about the subjunctive?), is it a passive-voice subjunctive-mood construction? Is it somehow in the active voice ?

The original query was intended for "Let the cake be eaten", which I had assumed to be a passive transformation of "eat the cake" the title and rest of the question are an attempt at generalization. Also note that I'm looking at this from a purely grammatical point of view, whether such constructions are silly or not is another matter.

related questions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122740/active-to-passive-voice-go-to-school-now) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159964/active-passive-voice-related-question/159969?noredirect=1#comment333654_159969)

Comment: *Let* is an imperative, but is often used to convey what other languages do with the subjunctive.  The unspoken subject of the verb *let* is *you.*  *It* is the direct object of the verb *let.*  *Be* is a bare infinitive, not a subjunctive in this case.  *Done* is the past participle of the verb *to do*.  *Let* is not passive, but *be done* is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/Jussive.htm) has a balanced article on **jussives** that examines different approaches.

I'd say that calling 'Let us pray' an imperative usage is stretching the term somewhat. It is far less hortative than '[Get] on your knees!'  In the linked article is:

> '[John] Lyons [Semantics, 1977: 747] argues that the imperative can
>   only be, strictly, second person, and never third person (or first
>   person). _This may, however, be no more than a terminological issue,
>   since first and third person 'imperatives' are often simply called
>   'jussives.'

Types of jussives are also addressed:

> Jussives include not only imperatives, as narrowly defined, but also
>   related non-imperative clauses, including some in subjunctive mood:
>
> Be sensible.
>
> You be quiet.
>
> Everybody listen.
>
> Let's forget it.
>
> Heaven help us.
>
> It is important that he keep this a secret.

...................

In 'Let it be done,' 'it' is referential (with preceding referent) and 'be done' is certainly passive. A modern not-too-near paraphrase is perhaps 'Get on with it, or make sure someone else does!' Far more imperative.