# Active to Passive

Tags: passive-voice, imperatives

Active:

> Don't ask me the question.

Passive:

> Don't let myself be asked the question by you.

Is it correct? If not, please provide the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Let myself* is not correct.
To start with something simpler, let's first try it without the imperative.  In this case we would change *You ask me a question* to something like

> I am asked a question by you.
>
> A question is asked to me by you.

Now, changing the original sentence to the imperative *Do not ask me a question* (with implied subject *you*), if we follow the rules layed out [here](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/changing-imperative-sentence-passive/), we would say something like

> Let me not be asked the question.
>
> Let not the question be asked to me.

The "let not" sounds archaic to me, and a native English speaker would probably not use it.  Therefore, you could instead say

> Do not let me be asked the question.
>
> Do not let the question be asked to me.

However, I agree with the advice in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/122764/46240): changing an imperative sentence (especially one starting with *do not*) is probably a bad idea, and would rarely be used in practice.